# C# - Creating a Boxplot in Oxyplot

Tags: c#, data-binding, boxplot, oxyplot

I try to get used to Oxyplot to create some charts in my C# application. So I wanted to create a Boxplot diagram with OxyPlot, but I am not able to get any results. I tried the "Getting Started" example with no problems but now I have no clue how to bind data to a `BoxplotSeries`. I read the documentation on GitHub for `BoxPlotSeries` but there are not much information listed and the examples help me neither. So can somebody can give me an example how to use `BoxPlotSeries` and bind data to it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to create a Boxplot with OxyPlot. Just use the Class BoxPlotSeries of OxyPlot, a List object which holds the Boxplots and a little bit of math. I used CategoryAxes for x axis to distinguish the Boxplots.

So for the future, here is the Code if somebody struggles with the same problem.

```
 public class Item
{
    #region Public Properties

    public string Label { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}

public class BoxPlotSeriesExample
{
    #region Public Constructors

    public BoxPlotSeriesExample()
    {
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Methods

    public PlotModel createBoxPlot()
    {
        const int boxes = 16;
        var plot = new PlotModel();
        var items = new Collection<Item>();

        for (int i = 1; i < boxes + 1; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new Item { Label = i.ToString() });
        }

        plot.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            MajorStep = 1,
            MinorStep = 0.25,
            TickStyle = TickStyle.Crossing,
            AbsoluteMaximum = 5.25,
            AbsoluteMinimum = -0.25
        });

        plot.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            ItemsSource = items,
            LabelField = "Label",
            IsTickCentered = true,
            TickStyle = TickStyle.None,
            AbsoluteMinimum = -1,
            AbsoluteMaximum = 17,
            IsZoomEnabled = false
        });

        var lineAnnotation = new LineAnnotation
        {
            Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal,
            Y = 5,
            LineStyle = LineStyle.Dash,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Color = OxyColor.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        plot.Annotations.Add(lineAnnotation);

        lineAnnotation = new LineAnnotation
        {
            Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal,
            Y = 1,
            LineStyle = LineStyle.Dash,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5,
            Color = OxyColor.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        plot.Annotations.Add(lineAnnotation);

        lineAnnotation = new LineAnnotation
        {
            Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal,
            Y = 4,
            LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5,
            Color = OxyColor.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        plot.Annotations.Add(lineAnnotation);

        lineAnnotation = new LineAnnotation
        {
            Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal,
            Y = 2,
            LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5,
            Color = OxyColor.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        plot.Annotations.Add(lineAnnotation);

        var s1 = new BoxPlotSeries();
        s1.Fill = OxyColor.FromRgb(0x1e, 0xb4, 0xda);
        s1.StrokeThickness = 1.1;
        s1.WhiskerWidth = 1;
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes; i++)
        {
            double x = i;
            var points = 5 + random.Next(15);
            var values = new List<double>();
            for (int j = 0; j < points; j++)
            {
                values.Add((random.NextDouble()) * 5);
            }

            values.Sort();
            var median = getMedian(values);
            int r = values.Count % 2;
            double firstQuartil = getMedian(values.Take((values.Count + r) / 2)); // 25%-Quartil
            double thirdQuartil = getMedian(values.Skip((values.Count - r) / 2)); // 75%-Quartil

            var iqr = thirdQuartil - firstQuartil; // Quartilabstand
            var step = 1.5 * iqr;
            var upperWhisker = thirdQuartil + step;
            upperWhisker = values.Where(v => v <= upperWhisker).Max();
            var lowerWhisker = firstQuartil - step;
            lowerWhisker = values.Where(v => v >= lowerWhisker).Min();
            var outliers = values.Where(v => v > upperWhisker || v < lowerWhisker).ToList();

            s1.Items.Add(new BoxPlotItem(x, lowerWhisker, firstQuartil, median, thirdQuartil, upperWhisker, outliers));
        }

        plot.Series.Add(s1);
        return plot;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Private Methods

    private static double getMedian(IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        var sortedInterval = new List<double>(values);
        sortedInterval.Sort();
        var count = sortedInterval.Count;
        if (count % 2 == 1)
        {
            return sortedInterval[(count - 1) / 2];
        }

        return 0.5 * sortedInterval[count / 2] + 0.5 * sortedInterval[(count / 2) - 1];
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to do it in WPF/XAML, if the answer is yes then you currently don't have the possibility to do it as there is no WPF wrapper for the BoxPlot Series.

I tried to port it myself, but ran into some problems, if you want to contribute please see the issue below on GitHub:

https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/425

**EDIT:** I just submitted a pull request with which you should be able to use a BoxPlot in WPF